# mongodb date comparison between ISO string and datetime

Tags: python, mongodb, date, pymongo, isodate

I have a MongoDB collection where the date attribute is stored in the following format

```
{'date': "2014-05-28T13:02:46"}
```

I receive a query from the user in my Python server which is in the format '2014-05-28' that I have to compare against 'date'. I wrote the following query in Pymongo but it fails.

```
 signup_date = datetime.date(2014,5,28)
 signed_up_users = usercollection.find({'customer_id':'abc','date' :{"$gte":signup_date}})
```

I believe it's a date conversion issue.However, I can't modify the collection 'date' which is a string. So, I believe I have to parse it but can't find a way to parse it in PyMongo.

Comment: It's not a date conversion issue except that you should probably be using a date type to store dates. What is your expected result? Should `2014-05-28` come before or after 1:02PM on the same day?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control on how the data gets stored. I only read from it. Basically the date 2014-05-28 is used as a lower bound for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this in the following way

```
signup_date_iso = datetime.date(2014,5,28).isoformat()
```

This converts into an ISO format date string that I can use to compare with the date strings stored in the database.